# Specify when UpdateProgress Control are displayed

Tags: asp.net, updateprogress

Does anyone have a resource or provide a code sample on when not to display an UpdatePrgress Control when a certain button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

in your Markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Initial page rendered."></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        Processing...
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

in your code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Introducing delay for demonstration.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Label1.Text = "Page refreshed at " +
        DateTime.Now.ToString();       
}
```

this should work, try it...

source: [Introduction to the UpdateProgress Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx)

Comment: I was looking for an example similar to the scenario explained under the "Specifying When UpdateProgress Controls Are Displayed" section in the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx